# CSS - Need to make wave animation with circles. Cannot alter HTML

Tags: html, css, animation

I have to make an animation of 5 balls of different colors that move in a wave. I am struggling with the different starting positions of the balls as the instructions say. And the position and color of the first-child goes last in the sequence of 5 balls for some reason.

Use this color palette (Links to an external site.) to style the div elements with the circle class as per the reference above. Each circle should be 50px in diameter.
Implement an animation so that the circles move up 100px, then move back down to their original position. The movement should have a duration of 1 second. Each ball should start the animation at a slightly different point in time so that they appear slightly out of phase. The overall effect is that they appear as an infinite looping ‘wave’.

Here is the HTML

```css
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color:antiquewhite;
  animation: circle 1s linear infinite;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.circle:first-child {animation-delay: -0.1s; background: #EF476F}
.circle:nth-child(2) {animation-delay: -0.2s; background: #FFD166;}
.circle:nth-child(3) {animation-delay: -0.4s; background: #06D6A0;}
.circle:nth-child(4) {animation-delay: -0.6s; background: #118AB2;}
.circle:nth-child(5) {animation-delay: -0.8s; background: #073B4C;}


@keyframes circle {
  0%, 100% {transform: translateY(0px);}
  50% {transform: translateY(100px);}
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1>CSS Challenges</h1>

  <section>
    <h2>Challenge 3</h2>  
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `nth-child()`. Your first circle element is actually the second child element in the container, because the first child element is the `<h2>`.
The `nth-child()` does not distinct by class so this method won't work.

However, the solution is found in another, more fitting selector `nth-of-type()`. This selector also can't distinguish by class name, but can by element type.

```css
.circle {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: antiquewhite;
 animation: circle 1s ease-in-out infinite; /* changed it to ease-in-out just for better visual result */
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
}

.circle:nth-of-type(1) { animation-delay: -0.1s; background: #EF476F }
.circle:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: -0.2s; background: #FFD166; }
.circle:nth-of-type(3) { animation-delay: -0.4s; background: #06D6A0; }
.circle:nth-of-type(4) { animation-delay: -0.6s; background: #118AB2; }
.circle:nth-of-type(5) { animation-delay: -0.8s; background: #073B4C; }


@keyframes circle {
 0%, 100% { transform: translateY(0px); }
 50% { transform: translateY(100px); }
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Challenges</h1>

  <section>
    <h2>Challenge 3</h2>  
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </section>
```

The selector will find the element with class `circle` and find the `nth` of its type - in this case `div`. If you add another element, like `<span class"circle"></span>`, it will get the styles of `.circle:nth-of-type(1)` because this is the first span with this class.